# zsh complaint 503: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew

Tags: macos, zsh, apple-m1, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to configure a few `alias` for my zsh shell but none of those I put into the `~/.zshrc` file seems to work, and when I try to `source ~/.zshrc` in my terminal, I got the complaint :

```
compinit:503: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew_cask
```

I have already gone through all the method provided from the answer here: [zsh problem: compinit:503: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65747286/zsh-problem-compinit503-no-such-file-or-directory-usr-local-share-zsh-site) , yet the problem persist.

I am running on M1 Macbook pro. From the answers, it seems the problem exists because `oh-my-zsh` doesn't know the Homebrew of M1 is under `/opt/homebrew`.

I have tried to run `brew doctor`, `brew cleanup` and also `brew install zsh-completions` but none solve the problem. I also tried to use

```
HOMEBREW_PREFIX=$(brew --prefix)
export FPATH="${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/share/zsh/site-functions:${FPATH}"
```

setting before running `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`
for solve the problem, but it turns out if I type `brew --prefix` in my terminal, I am still getting `/usl/local` in return.

I am wondering how can I solve the problem from here?

---

Here attach is my `~/.zshrc` file:

```
# Enable Powerlevel10k instant prompt. Should stay close to the top of ~/.zshrc.
# Initialization code that may require console input (password prompts, [y/n]
# confirmations, etc.) must go above this block; everything else may go below.
if [[ -r "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh" ]]; then
  source "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh"
fi

# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"

# Set list of themes to pick from when loading at random
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random will cause zsh to load
# a theme from this variable instead of looking in $ZSH/themes/
# If set to an empty array, this variable will have no effect.
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion.
# Case-sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment one of the following lines to change the auto-update behavior
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode disabled  # disable automatic updates
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode auto      # update automatically without asking
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode reminder  # just remind me to update when it's time

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# zstyle ':omz:update' frequency 13

# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# You can also set it to another string to have that shown instead of the default red dots.
# e.g. COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="%F{yellow}waiting...%f"
# Caution: this setting can cause issues with multiline prompts in zsh < 5.7.1 (see #5765)
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in $ZSH/plugins/
# Custom plugins may be added to $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(
     git
     zsh-interactive-cd
     zsh-navigation-tools
     zsh-autosuggestions
     zsh-syntax-highlighting
)

HOMEBREW_PREFIX=$(brew --prefix)
export FPATH="${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/share/zsh/site-functions:${FPATH}"

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.p10k.zsh.
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh
```

Comment: Does the directory mentioned here exist? What do you have in `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions`? Aside from this I would track down the `compinit` command which causes the error, i.e.  turn on `set -x` and source your .zshrc again. This will of course produce a lot of output, but in the end you should find the offending `compinit` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may imported when you use your new MacBook(M chip series), but you use the syncing function from the old Intel chip MacBook.
The saved location is changed

You can try `ln -fsv /opt/homebrew/completions/zsh/_brew /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew` to link the previous cached link into the old one.